# Cordova/Phonegap 2.5 + Sharekit Plugin + FacebookConnect

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sharekit

I'm developing an app using cordova phonegap 2.5.0 and I want to implement both sharing in iOs and facebookConnect. I'm using Sharekit 2 + Sharekit Plugin for phonegap and i'm having no issues with the sharing, but some trouble with facebook connect. I can make the connect itself using the built in function:

```
facebookConnect( );
```

and it seems to work, but I need to retrieve **the facebook Uid** after the connect. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help somebody else...

Because I can't find any documentation about my question I managed to solve in this way:

Use the official facebook SDK and facebook connect plugin - Instruction here https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ and here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin - for the facebook connect. It is full of example and pretty simple to implement.

Added sharekit to my project with granular install - Instrutions here https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Granular-install - avoiding to installa the facebook part.

Added ShareKit Plugin - Instructions here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ShareKitPlugin - and comment out from ShareKitPlugin.m all the refence to Facebook.

Now the share trough ShareKit is working and I'm going to manage the facebook share trough the official SDK.

Hope it could help...

Answer (score 0):

@Teo_ne: After spending a lot of time, I found that Phonegap_Facebook_Plugin only work with IOS v6+, not support IOS v5.x due to the Social.framework.